# Connect to postgresql using php pdo - not working

Tags: apache2, php, connection, postgresql

I have Ubuntu 18.04, apache2, PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, and PostgreSQL 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04) running on localhost:5432. I am trying to make a PDO connection to a database. But it's not working. The phpinfo() page shows that PDO support is enabled for pgsql.

The owner of db is postgres, database name testdb, and server is localhost.

I write the following code but when I run it, it shows no output i.e. neither connection is successful nor error msg.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "test123";
$dbname = "testdb";

$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(!$conn){
echo "error in conn";
} else {
echo "success";
}

?>
```

How to make it work ?

Comment: It doesn't help. This PDO code is working on windows. I take it from there.

Comment: I couldn't find a code example for ubuntu but I think same code should work here too as PDO is probably meant for that.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108784/connect-to-postgresql-using-pdo

Comment: I tried methods in that thread but it didn't work.

Comment: <?php
$conn = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=testdb;user=postgres;password=test123;host=localhost');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(!$conn){
echo "err";
} else {
echo "conn";
}

?>

Comment: one of the problem is it doesn't even shows the err msg.

Comment: Please add this to the error branch: `print_r(error_get_last());`

Comment: @DanielVérité: thank you for the help. It started working already. There was some problem in communication between postgresql & phppgadmin.I declare db using phppgadmin,I checked from cli & it doesn't appear there though phppgadmin was showing it in posgres space.I dropped it & declared db again from cli and the connection start working. Its visible from phppgadmin too.